# React.js loader for sass modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create my own react bundle, so I can better understand react flow.
I have my css loader and modules works fine with this loader:

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
```

Then I can do `import classes from ...` and attach my classes with `className={classes.Someclass}`

I need similar setup for css files and when I tried to replicate similar setup I got error: "Try different loader for such file types"
How can I setup loader for css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 2,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        }),
      }
```